# When exactly does Čech cohomology coincide with singular cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, cech-cohomology

I believe that it is shown in EH Spanier's "Algebraic Topology" that if  is paracompact and locally contractible, then singular cohomology and Čech cohomology of  coincide, with coefficients in any abelian group. Is the converse true?

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments, a compact but not locally compact space is a counterexample (take subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by union of lines $y=mx$, $m \in \mathbb{Q}$).
However, having read some of the book now it seems that the condition can be relaxed to (Hausdorff) paracompact and homologically locally connected. It seems intuitively that contractible spaces are homologically locally connected (not sure though). Is this the case and, if so, is the converse now true or what is a counterexample?

Comment: Take any contractible space which fails to be paracompact or locally contractible.

Comment: See also this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4390308/hnx-s-and-check-hnx-s-when-x-setminus-s-is-an-n-manifold-hawa

Comment: @Tyrone Having read the some of the book now it seems that the condition can be  relaxed to paracompact and homologically locally connected. It seems intuitively that contractible spaces are homologically locally connected (not sure though). Do you know if in this case the converse would be true or of any counterexamples?